# Java - JFrame break Components like FlowLayout, but order them vertically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, flowlayout

since some hours I am trying to create a JFrame whit following behavior:
I have a Title (with maybe an Image included) -This is centered at the top. -> Check
The rest of this JFrame should be filled with JPanel.

The first JPanel should be placed in the center on top. The second JPanel should be placed under the first and so on. When the first JPanel runs out of the screen, a second row needs to be created.
I dont care if they are reordered or not. Here is a drawing i prepared to show what I want:
[Example - I need one of that behaviors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBtA9.png)

I have tried out so many combination of different Layouts.. But still can't find the right solution.

Here is my code, which is working fine besides the fact, that my panels are ordered from left to right instead of from top to down.. :(

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class myFrameClass extends JFrame {

    myFrameClass() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
        GraphicsConfiguration[] gc = gs[0].getConfigurations();
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLocation(gc[0].getBounds().x, gc[0].getBounds().y);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        add(getHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(getPanels());

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanels() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        int cnt = 6;

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            p.add(getPanel());
        }   

        return p;
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.RED);
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        return p;
    }

    private JPanel getHeader() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel("Titel"));
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new myFrameClass();
    }
}
```

I also found [Oracle VerticalFlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/javatools/ui/layout/VerticalFlowLayout.html) but was not able to access it. Might it help me? In case - how to use it?

Otherwise.. How to use JFrame to archive that behavior?
Thank you

Comment: If the user makes the frame bigger, how is the extra space to be distributed?

Comment: I'd suggest using a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).  You'll have to calculate how many columns you want to have before you define the layout.  Let's say you want to have two columns with six JPanels.  You'll have to add them to the GridLayout in 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6 order to get the JPanels to go down the column.